# Why does my game freeze inside coroutine?

Tags: unity-game-engine, while-loop, coroutine

sorry if this question is very basic. I created a coroutine that detects collisions every 5 seconds. Inside this coroutine I would like to execute an animation for 3 seconds so I came up with this bit of code:

```
private IEnumerator OnCollisionStay2D(Collision2D collision)
{
    if (collision.collider.tag == "mama") {
        //interrupt movement
        float currentTime = Time.time;
        float madBegin = Time.time;
        while (currentTime - madBegin < 3)
        {
            personAnimator.runtimeAnimatorController = Resources.Load("Animations/human1mad_0") as RuntimeAnimatorController;
            currentTime = Time.time;
            Debug.Log(currentTime);
        }
        isAngry = true;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(5);
}
```

I logged the elaped time in the while loop and `currentTime` does not seem to be updating. As a result, the elapsed time equals 0 and my while loop never exits. Furthermore since this is executing in a coroutine that is supposed to run concurrently I don't get why a nonexiting while loop would freeze the entire game.

Clarification is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-time.html) on `Time.time`

> The time at the beginning of this frame (Read Only)

This means that your `Time.time` will not change over the course of your loop so the difference between `currentTime` and `madBegin` will always be 0.

[Time.realtimeSinceStartup](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Time-realtimeSinceStartup.html) may be what you're looking for.